# How to transcode raw uncompressed RTP to an H264 RTSP stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am new to streaming and am trying to figure out how to transcode streams via ffmpeg.

I have a few raw rtp uncompressed streams where some are on address 239.x.x.x and others are on 169.x.x.x.

I want to setup an RTSP server to grab those streams and transcode them into H264 and stream them out to a new address and port.

I have tried some ffmpeg commands but I keep getting errors about having to compile ffmpeg with pthreads.

I have no idea how to do that so does anyone know what commands I can use that will work with the current windows version of ffmpeg?

For now, I am just trying to save the stream to a file to see if that works. Command I am using is:

```
ffmpeg -i rtp://224.1.1.10:6972 transcoded test.mp4
```

and the return I get in the command line is

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.3.1 (GCC) 20190414
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100

[udp @ 000002cb292abf40] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)  
[udp @ 000002cb292bc200] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)  
rtp://224.1.1.10:6972: Immediate exit requested  
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

Comment: Yes that is the complete log

Comment: Use a build that supports pthreads, or try TCP instead of UDP. If your server outputs TCP you can try adding the input option(s) `-rtsp_flags prefer_tcp` and/or `-rtsp_transport tcp` (place them before `-i`).

Comment: Thanks. Getting closer. I now get an error       
setsocket(IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP): no such device. I can take it from here now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try TCP instead of UDP. If your server outputs TCP you can try adding the input option(s) `-rtsp_flags prefer_tcp` and/or `-rtsp_transport tcp` (place them before `-i`).

Or use a build of `ffmpeg` that supports pthreads.